# JavaScript: Make <select onchange> or <option onclick> keyboard-accessible

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility, wcag2.0

Similar questions have been asked before, but I'm looking for the "opposite" solution than all the others ;-)

I need a JavaScript event that fires when a user *decides* for an `option` in a `select` field.

What do I mean by *decide*:

- Mouse: Click to expand the `select`, then click to select any `option`.
- Keyboard: Either:

  - Press the UP/DOWN keys to "scroll" through the options (without expanding the `select`), then press ENTER/TAB to select. Or:
  - Press ALT+DOWN to expand the `select`, then use the UP/DOWN keys to scroll through the options, and finally press ENTER/TAB to select.

Non-perfect solutions I've found so far:

- `onclick` on each `option`: Firefox & Internet Explorer: Works for mouse, but not for keyboard. Chrome: Doesn't work at all.
- `onchange` on the `select`: Firefox: Works as expected. Chrome & Internet Explorer: Fires too early when using just the UP/DOWN keys (without expanding the `select`): In the users' mind, they are just *scrolling* through the available options, not actually *selecting* anything yet.
  Albeit being popular, this approach violates WCAG: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20-20120103/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html
- `onblur` on the `select`: Firefox & Chrome & Internet Explorer: Fires too late, only when actually *leaving* the `select`.
- `onkeydown` on the `select`, plus evaluating the `keyCode`: Looks like a hassle to me, cause there might be (or turn out) other ways to confirm something than pressing the ENTER key (maybe on mobile devices).

The only solution I've found, having perfect accessibility, is ugly:

- Having an explicit `submit` button and binding the event to this.

So (finally) my question is: Do you know any other way to achieve this without the `submit` button?

Comment: Changing the default behavior of a select element is likely to be confusing to users. Not sure why you think having an explicit button is ugly.

Comment: You say the change event on the select violates WCAG: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/NOTE-UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20-20120103/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html

I DISAGREE: It is totally reasonable to expect users of the user agent (browser) to know how to use that functionality. Therefore, if they are just browsing the options, it is reasonable to expect that they should open the select element using the spacebar first.

If this is not the case, then the user agent should be changed such that the arrow key use is interpreted the way users expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [the `onInput` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input):

> The DOM `input` event is fired synchronously when the value of an `<input>`, `<select>`, or `<textarea>` element is changed.

Right now, [Firefox doesn’t support the event on `<select>` elements](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=312094), but since `onChange` works like you want in Firefox, you can pick and choose. (You want an `onChange` listener for [backwards compatibility](https://caniuse.com/input-event), anyway.)